# Recovering Lost Data

Tags: data-recovery

I was just wondering if you have any information on getting my data back on corrupted micro sd card. I have tried ideas off Youtube but they did not work. Thank you

Comment: It is customary, to provide details of exact measures taken to rectify the situation. Commands, links to tutorials, or videos etc. Welcome to askUbuntu.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a USB sd card reader, try using that to mount the card instead of through the device that the card belongs to (like instead of plugging the cable into your phone/ camera from your computer). This just makes sure there really is a problem with the card and not with your device.

The second benefit of using a USB adapter is that you can touch the card to see if it is hot. If the card is burning up then you have a short and there is no way to recover any data- this usually happens if you accidentally bent the card slightly or if there has been physical damage to the card. How hot is too hot? It will almost burn your fingers...

The circuitry is really fragile in these cards so it doesn't take much to fry them. I have never had any luck with recovery software. Hard lesson learned - never keep anything valuable on SD flash- it is by far the least reliable storage medium.

Comment: May be this helps https://askubuntu.com/questions/579250/recover-data-from-a-formatted-windows-hard-drive/579288#579288